# How to generate a random signal in time domain with a defined frequency bandwidth ? (example : bandwidth 0-60Hz)

Tags: python, signal-processing, fft, frequency, psd

I want to generate on python a signal that is random in the time domain but i want it to have a bandwidth in the frequency domain equals to 0-60 hz.

I dont know from where to start. I'm new to python.

Comment: In frequency domain you could generate non zero amplitudes randomly inside the range 0..60 Hz, then convert them to time domain.

Comment: What Sembei suggested, I would just add random phase as well (generate random complex numbers). Where to start? Take a look at `numpy` and its [ifft function](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fft.ifft.html)